# DTO automapping: any benefits to use record instead of class

Tags: c#, c#-10.0, c#-record-type

I have the classic situation: several layers and use DTO classes to pass data between each other.

```
public class DownloadCenterFileElementViewModel
{
    public int FileID { get; init; }
    public string FileNameFriendly { get; init; }
    public string FileNameUnique { get; init; }
    public long ContentLength { get; init; }
    public DateTime DateLastUpdated { get; init; }
}

public class DownloadCenterFileElementDto
{
    public int FileID { get; init; }
    public string FileNameFriendly { get; init; }
    public string FileNameUnique { get; init; }
    public long ContentLength { get; init; }
    public DateTime DateLastUpdated { get; init; }
}

CreateMap<DownloadCenterFileElementDto, DownloadCenterFileElementViewModel>();
```

so, I use `Automapper` to map data and can't use the primary constructor form of `record`.

Is there anything beneficial about using `record` instead of `class` in my case?

Comment: Records map to JSON well

Comment: If you want the semantics of a record such as memberwise equality.

Comment: C#10 has no primary constructor. This feature was introduced in C#12.

Comment: Using record gives you a more concise definition syntax.

Comment: Does it matter if there's any benefit if you can't use it? This question is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

The performance comparison between classes and records when using a mapper in C# depends on factors like object size, mutability, mapper implementation, and application context. For small and simple objects, the difference might be negligible. Records can offer efficiency with immutable fields. Mapper library choices and manual implementation impact performance. Practical performance may vary, so testing in the specific application context is crucial.